# jQuery smooth scrolling when click menu

Tags: jquery

My jQuery smooth scrolling works when

```
<a href="#services">Services</a>
```

But I want smooth scroll when

```
<a href="http://website.com/#services">Services</a>
```

This markup. Is this possible?

the jQuery I am using

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Is `http://website.com/#services` just any website?  Or is it a website you control?

Comment: it was an example domain. The correct answer works on any domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [substr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) to extract the targeted string from your `href` :

```
$('.nav a').click(function (e) {
    var linkHref = $(this).attr("href");
    var idElement = linkHref.substr(linkHref.indexOf("#"));
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(idElement).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/n4kxctcm/)

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But when I use full URL in href, bootstrap's scrollspy isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: What your full URLs look like ?

Comment: When use `<a href="#services">Services</a>` scrollspy is working but when use `<a href="http://website.com/#services">Services</a>` it is not working i mean.

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault()` : https://jsfiddle.net/n4kxctcm/1/ (and don't forget to add e for function :`$('.nav a').click(function (e) `)

Comment: Just added the script above in a scrollspy demo, editing links so they look like yours, and it's working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVmBP - Can you provide more details on what's wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76656/discussion-between-rasel-ahmed-and-edensource).

Comment: Got a little problem on it. When I add an external link it is not working. Do you know why? here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4kxctcm/2/

Comment: It is because of the preventDefault(). You can try adding a class to the external A tag, and use .not(.'yourClass') to the selector: https://jsfiddle.net/6urje8mr/

Comment: No. I don't want to add a class there. Is there any another way. I afraid to ask so I didn't replied.

Comment: You can try to exclude special index using .eq(), or exclude A tags which .text() match Google.com for exemple. This is the only fix I can see.